# akka kafka consumer poll speed backpressure

Tags: apache-kafka, akka-stream

The project uses akka stream kafka, and one process is commencing several kafka topics. When I receive a message from kafka, I am processing the business logic of pre-processing and updating to couchbase. At this time, even if the data generation speed of the kafka producer becomes very fast, the consumer wants to control the speed of the concume. When registering the kafka consumer, you specified options such as "max.pull.records" and "fetch.max.bytes", but the cpu value is abnormally high because the speed of the conclusion is too fast. Is there a way to control the speed of the concume?

```
Consumer.plainSource(ConsumerConfig, Subscriptions.topics("topicName")
        .mapAsync(parallelism, Function)
        .delay(Duration.ofNanos(1L), DelayOverflowStrategy.backpressure());
```

I had no choice but to adjust the consume speed with the code giving delay as above, but it is too slow. Please help me.

```
2022:04:28 10:19:49.566 INFO    --- [akka.actor.consume-dispatcher-25] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig[logAll:347] : ConsumerConfig values: 
allow.auto.create.topics = true
auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
auto.offset.reset = earliest
bootstrap.servers = [127.0.0.1:9092]
check.crcs = true
client.dns.lookup = default
client.id = 
client.rack = 
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
enable.auto.commit = true
exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 10485760
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = group1
group.instance.id = null
heartbeat.interval.ms = 5000
interceptor.classes = []
internal.leave.group.on.close = true
isolation.level = read_uncommitted
key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
max.poll.records = 100
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.login.class = null
sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
session.timeout.ms = 10000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

it`s my consumer config.

Comment: The consumers are independent from producers so they control how fast they want/can consume messages. You can add delays or how fast a consumer polls kafka via `akka.kafka.consumer.poll-interval` config parameter but you have to be careful doing it. Kafka is polling based system so if there are no polls coming within configurable amount of time, it will initiate re-balancing of consumers and this may result in duplicate processing.

Comment: i updated my consumer config, but there`s no poll-interval.....